# Android Navigation Drawer Icon remove right margin

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar

so I'm fairly new to Java and Android development and I've hit a snag. 
So I have created a custom Actionbar with much more height. It has at least 1 visible textview (depending on the fragment). My issue is I want my textviews aligned to the left of the app bar (directly below the nav drawer icon) but when my nav drawer button is generated in the top left it pushes my views to the right.

Does anyone know how to stop the toolbar's child views being essentially pushed over when the icon is added. (code below)

App Action Bar XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


tools:context="com.arcturusapps.grassrootsorganiser.MainActivity">

<!--TODO: Fix the Hard Coded Height -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_grass"

        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tool_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Team Organiser"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12pt" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_arc_header" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Main Activity Java:

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include

        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzUlL.jpg) 
[How it Currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN6GF.jpg)

P.S I am aware I shouldn't manually set 'dp' values for margins etc. at this point I am just trying to get it to look right. I'll go back and make it more dynamically scalable later.

Comment: You should consider using a CollapsingToolbarLayout then. It handles position of the title and even scrolling.

Comment: Hey efeturi, thanks for the reply. I'd be willing to try that, however in that case when the navedrawer toggle icon is added how do I ensure it doesn't push things over like it currently does. As i cant even find where that is defined.

Comment: The CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't know of the nav icons it's main job is to provide a collapsing title. Thing is, however, that you set the margins on that title so you have control over where the title is placed.